# history-search-backward ignores search text after first space character?

Tags: zsh, autocomplete, tab-completion

I use a lot of git commands and since they are mostly 2-word command names, matching doesn't find the closest match. For example:

```
# type in some commands
git checkout -
git status
mvn test

# try to autocomplete based on the history. I want "git checkout -" to be filled in, but instead "git status" is filled in.
git c<history-search-backward>
git status
```

Notice the `space` and `c` that I typed in are ignored in the autocomplete.

I assume this is some shortcoming of the zsh completion system. Is this true? Or am I misunderstanding the functionality?

Comment: Bash reverse history search handles this without any problems ... just sayin ...

Comment: Good to know, I didn't want to go through testing that out myself. I guess i need to file a bug against the ZSH source code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `history-search-backward` looks only for lines beginning with the first word of the current command line. This is neither a shortcoming nor a bug, but intentional.

For your use-case you want to use the widget `history-beginning-search-backward` instead. This searches the history based on everything from the beginning up to the cursor position. (This is the equivalent to the *bash's* `history-search-backward` command)

Comment: I'm curious - why is it designed this way? Is it because most use cases deal with 1-word commands, and we don't wish to match against arguments?